# Toggle buttons change textview simultaneously

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set my toggle buttons like radio buttons so that when I click between the buttons, my textview updates. And when I click on the plus or minus button on the sides of my textview, that the buttons update along with the textview.

I have a buggy video to show: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfx2r3t3umhgc4p/VIDEO0048.mp4?dl=0 to reflect what I am trying to do.

I have two questions on what I am doing below:

1) I think my for loop here logic is flawed: Does this make sense? :

```
// **Loop through this group then for each child, set your listener
                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                        child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
                    }
```

2) How can I make this code cleaner? How can I refactor it?

```
//onClickListener method that returns an interface
private View.OnClickListener createClickListener(final int value) {
    return new View.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            buttonValue = value;
            buttonState = true;

            ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;
            RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) clickedButton.getParent();

            if (clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                System.out.println("Button Value: " + Integer.toString(buttonValue));
                num.setText( Integer.toString(buttonValue));
                System.out.println(buttonState);
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                System.out.println(buttonState);
                System.out.println("Is this called?");
            }
            System.out.println("Check changed listener called");


           for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View nextChild = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (!(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (nextChild.getId() != clickedButton.getId() || !clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }

    };
}

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

                //Get the inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                //inflate the root layout
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection, null);

                final int[] counter = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
                num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));

                //scores toggle buttons
                zero = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_zero);
                one = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_one);
                two = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_two);
                three = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_three);
                four = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_four);
                five = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_five);
                six = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_six);
                seven = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_seven);
                eight = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_eight);
                nine = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_nine);
                ten = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_ten);


                final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup);

                // **Loop through this group then for each child, set your listener
                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                    child.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(i));
                }

                final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
                final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);

                zero.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(0));
                one.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(1));
                two.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(2));
                three.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(3));
                four.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(4));
                five.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(5));
                six.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(6));
                seven.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(7));
                eight.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(8));
                nine.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(9));
                ten.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(10));

                plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                                counter[0]++;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                    View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                    if (i == buttonValue) {
                                        tb2.setChecked(true);
                                    } else {
                                        tb2.setChecked(false);
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.println(num.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (minus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 10) && (counter[0] > 0)) {
                                counter[0]--;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                buttonValue = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                    View nextChild = group.getChildAt(i);
                                    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                    if (i == buttonValue) {
                                        tb2.setChecked(true);
                                    } else {
                                        tb2.setChecked(false);
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.println(num.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: In your loop, do you have any code in the onClickListener? If not, it will listen for a click but do nothing, correct?

Comment: Yes, the onclick listener is above. Do you see it?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [Android doc for the ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html). Especially the part on the bottom about the `OnCheckedChangeListener` should be interesting for you.

Comment: I did almost exactly that. Can you take a look at what I'm doing and what I did wrong?

Comment: No you do not. You loop through all children and add `OnClickListeners`. The example is using `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: You could create one `OnCheckedChangeListener` for each `ToggleButton`/`TextView` combination. That way you don't need to look them up in case of an event.

Comment: Actually, it seems that is not the problem. I could just a regular on Click Listener and it would still work :D